# How to get 1 or 0 according to the content of a list

Tags: python, list, function

I'm scraping with python and I have a list made at most of two letters(R and D), where the content can be always the same (i.e. all the elements are R or alternatively D) or it can be that there are some D and some R. How can I get 1 if the list is made of either R only (or D only) and 0 if there are both D and R? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this homework? If so, you should say so. In any case, post samples of what you have already tried.

Comment: `len(set(my_list)) % 2`

Comment: Yes, sorry...it is homework. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just check to see if all the elements are identical.

```
val = 1 if all(elem == items[0] for elem in items) else 0
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well until I find some private informations on the website and so I've an empty list. Python gives me this error "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list". I tried to set an exception when the length of the list is 0 with the command if but it doesn't fix the error.